# Can you transition using Fade specifying all elements, without listing individually?

Tags: flex4, transition

I've got the beginning of an air app, and I'm trying to transition between the states using Fade (a Sequence that should, in theory, fade out, then fade the next state in.) Is there a way to target it to fade out ALL the elements, or will I need to use targets="..." and list every element?

I've tried nesting all the elements in a Group, but that isn't seeming to work.

Shortened version of my current code:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="HomeScreen"/>
    <s:State name="EnemyBuilder"/>
    <s:State name="EncyclopediaBuilder"/>
</s:states>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Transition toState="*" fromState="*" >
        <s:Sequence >
            <s:Fade alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="250" target="{wrapper}" />
            <s:Fade alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="250" target="{wrapper}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition> 
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Group id="wrapper" includeIn="HomeScreen, EnemyBuilder, EncyclopediaBuilder" >

<s:BorderContainer id="encounter" includeIn="HomeScreen" 
                   x="49" y="99" width="200" height="44" 
                   styleName="falseButton"
                   rollOut="alphaOver(event)" rollOver="alphaOver(event)" click="currentState='EncyclopediaBuilder'" >
    <s:Label x="48" y="8" color="#000000" fontFamily="Arial" text="Create a new encounter" />
    <s:Label x="48" y="24" color="#000000" fontStyle="italic" text="Single encounter" />
    <s:Image x="10" y="10" source="assets/001_01.png" />
<s:BorderContainer id="back" includeIn="EncyclopediaBuilder" 
                   right="20" bottom="20" width="200" height="44"
                   styleName="falseButton"
                   rollOut="alphaOver(event)" rollOver="alphaOver(event)"
                   click="currentState='HomeScreen'" >
    <s:Label x="48" y="16" color="#000000" fontFamily="Arial" text="Save and Return"/>
    <s:Image x="10" y="10" source="assets/001_01.png"/>
</s:BorderContainer>        
</s:BorderContainer></s:Group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use something like the following:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="HomeScreen"/>
    <s:State name="EnemyBuilder"/>
    <s:State name="EncyclopediaBuilder"/>
</s:states>
<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition toState="*" fromState="*" >
        <s:Sequence target="{wrapper}">
            <s:Fade alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="250" />
            <s:Fade alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="250" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition> 
</s:transitions>

<s:Group id="wrapper">

<s:BorderContainer id="encounter" includeIn="HomeScreen" 
                   x="49" y="99" width="200" height="44" 
                   styleName="falseButton"
                   rollOut="alphaOver(event)" rollOver="alphaOver(event)" click="currentState='EncyclopediaBuilder'" >
    <s:Label x="48" y="8" color="#000000" fontFamily="Arial" text="Create a new encounter" />
    <s:Label x="48" y="24" color="#000000" fontStyle="italic" text="Single encounter" />
    <s:Image x="10" y="10" source="assets/001_01.png" />
<s:BorderContainer id="back" includeIn="EncyclopediaBuilder" 
                   right="20" bottom="20" width="200" height="44"
                   styleName="falseButton"
                   rollOut="alphaOver(event)" rollOver="alphaOver(event)"
                   click="currentState='HomeScreen'" >
    <s:Label x="48" y="16" color="#000000" fontFamily="Arial" text="Save and Return"/>
    <s:Image x="10" y="10" source="assets/001_01.png"/>
</s:BorderContainer>        
</s:BorderContainer></s:Group>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, mostly. (it was what I was aiming for, despite not quite yet working the way I want) - (Now I'm looking for a way to delay the state change until the middle of the sequence)